# UI Logic in WinRT - MVVM

Tags: mvvm, windows-runtime, mvvm-light

Where should UI logic be in WindowsRT MVVM application? Putting it on ViewModel makes it really "fat" and I guess we lose one of MVVM pattern advantage - splitting work between designers and programmers becomes pretty hard. However I'm creating few "dynamic buttons" and coupling between these buttons and commands for them which reside in ViewModel isn't straightforward. What's is the best way of handling UI logic? I really miss triggers funcionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it doesn't fit in a view model - put it in code behind. If you want it reusable - create a custom control or an attached behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Does it make sense to have multiple view models?

For example having a View Model for your page and then more specific view models (as properties from the main, or aggregate view model) for custom controls?

It keeps things testable, and re-usable...